# How do I use eclipse Data Tools wizards?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I'm working on a small eclipse/RCP application, which will require some Database and Table management and was wondering, how I can use the Wizards and Views which are included in Eclipse DTP. There should be a way to use DTP to configure the required stuff...

I'd appreciate a short example how to call a wizard to select a database and where the information goes to once submitted.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you need to determine is whether DTP will even work in an RCP app. Many Eclipse Tools plugins are designed only for use in Eclipse IDE.

I would start by asking this on the DTP project's forum. If the answer to the RCP compatibility is yes, the folks on that forum will be able to help you out with instructions on how to launch the wizards, etc.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=3

Comment: Dunno about that. I mean... that's the whole point of the eclipse platform, isn't it? If I build an RCP app, I should be able to use any plugin; given the proper API.
I already posted to the DTP Community. Unfortunately, it seems to be visited as frequently as the Nevada desert.

Comment: The plugin reasoning is correct to an extent, but there is a set of plugins that make an Eclipse RCP app into an Eclipse IDE. In particular, the plugins that deal with workspace and resource concepts (IWorkspace/IProject/IFile). If DTP depends on those plugins, it will not work in an RCP app that lacks a workspace.

Answer (score -1):

You have to Open the Database Development Perspective. Define a new Connection in the Datasource Explorer. Create a SQL File in your Project and set the previously defined connection. then press the right key strokes to execute the sql on the connection you have set.

to lookup the key bindings open the preferences window->preferences. then open generar->keys and enter "database tools" to filter just the key bindings for the database tools.

Comment: -1 for not reading the question. It is asking how to launch DTP wizards programmatically, not how to use DTP as an end-user.